# Why do I get the following errors?(Errors at end of post)

Tags: java, inheritance

I've made the following classes and subclasses.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

   public class ShapeTester{ 
     //--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
     // Read the dimensions of various 3-D shapes from an input file, then 
     // displays pertinent information about each shape. 
     //--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
     public static void main (String[] args){ 
       try{ 
          Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File("shapes.txt")); 
          double width, length, height, side, radius; 

          // Read the data from the input file 
          while (scan.hasNext()){ 
             String shapeType = scan.next(); 

             if (shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("cylinder")){ 
                radius = scan.nextDouble(); 
                height = scan.nextDouble(); 
                System.out.println (new Cylinder (radius, height)); 
             } 
             if (shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("cone")){ 
                radius = scan.nextDouble(); 
                height = scan.nextDouble(); 
                System.out.println (new Cone (radius, height)); 
             }
             if (shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("cuboid")){ 
                length = scan.nextDouble(); 
                width = scan.nextDouble();
                height = scan.nextDouble(); 
                System.out.println (new Cuboid (length, width)); 
             }
          } 
       } 
       catch (Exception except){ 
          System.err.println(except); 
       } 
     } 
    }//end class ShapeTester



public abstract class Shape{ 
   abstract public double computeArea(); 
   abstract public double computePerimeter(); 
}//end class Shape




import java.text.*; 
public class Circle extends Shape{ 
 protected double radius; 
 protected static DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.##"); 

 public Circle (double rad){ 
   radius = rad; 
 } 

 public double computeArea(){ 
   return Math.pow(radius,2) * 3.14; 
 } 

 public double computePerimeter(){ 
   return radius * 6.28; 
 } 

 public String toString(){ 
   return "Circle: radius is " + form.format(radius) + 
   "\nperimeter is " + form.format(computePerimeter()) + 
   ", area is " + form.format(computeArea()); 
 } 
} //end class Circle






public class Cylinder extends Circle{ 
   private double height; 

   public Cylinder (double rad, double hei){ 
      super(rad); 
      height = hei; 
   } 

   // Returns the calculated value of face height  
   public double faceHeight(){ 
      return height; 
   }

   // Returns the calculated value of face area  
   public double faceArea(){ 
      return faceHeight() * radius * 6.28; 
   } 

   // Returns the calculated value of the surface area  
   public double computeArea(){ 
      return faceArea() + super.computeArea() + super.computeArea(); 
   } 

   // Returns the calculated value of the volume  
   public double computeVolume(){ 
      return super.computeArea() * height; 
   } 

   public String toString(){ 
      return "Cylinder: Height is " + form.format(height) + 
      "\nperimeter of base is " + form.format(computePerimeter()) + 
      ", area is " + form.format(computeArea()) + 
      "\nvolume is " + form.format(computeVolume()) + "\n"; 
   } 
}//end class Cylinder
```

> And up to here the program works perfectly. I can compile ShapeTester
>   and I receive the expected results for each value.(That is before I
>   inserted the if command for the cuboid) (There is also an if command
>   for cone there, which works too, I just didn't include the cone class
>   because this was long enough already.)

```
import java.text.*; 
public class Rectangle extends Shape{ 
 protected double length; 
 protected double width;
 protected static DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("0.##"); 

 public Rectangle (double len, double wid){ 
   length = len;
   width = wid; 
 } 

 public double computeArea(){ 
   return length * width; 
 }  

 public double computePerimeter(){ 
   return (2*length) + (2*width); 
 } 

 public String toString(){ 
   return "Rectangle: length is " + form.format(length) + 
   "\nwidth is " + form.format(width) +
   "\nperimeter is " + form.format(computePerimeter()) + 
   ", area is " + form.format(computeArea()); 
 } 
}//end class Rectangle
```

And this class compiles fine as well.
The following class is the one that gives me a problem.

```
public class Cuboid extends Rectangle{ 
   private double height;

   public Cuboid (double len, double wid, double hei){ 
      super(len);
      super(wid);
      height = hei;
   } 

   // Returns the calculated value of the surface area 
   public double computeArea(){ 
      return (2 * height * width) + (2 * super.computeArea()) + (2 * length * height) ; 
   } 

   // Returns the calculated value of the volume  
   public double computeVolume(){ 
      return super.computeArea() * height; 
   } 

   public String toString(){ 
      return "Rectangle Cuboid: Height is " + form.format(height) + 
      "\nlength is " + form.format(length) + 
      "\nwidth is " + form.format(width) +
      "\nperimeter of base is " + form.format(computePerimeter()) + 
      ", area is " + form.format(computeArea()) + 
      "\nvolume is " + form.format(computeVolume()) + "\n"; 
   } 
}//end class Cuboid
```

And when I try to compile this last class, I get these errors, yet I have followed the same format as I have for the other class(Cylinder). Could someone please tell me why?

```
Cuboid.java:5: error: constructor Rectangle in class Rectangle cannot be applied to given types;
      super(len);
      ^
  required: double,double
  found: double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Cuboid.java:6: error: call to super must be first statement in constructor
      super(wid);
           ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Don't follow the format of some other class. Follow the format your class is expecting. What don't you understand about the errors?

Answer (score 2):

[You must call `super` exactly as the super constructor is defined.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) You wouldn't expect to pass width and height to a `Rectangle` constructor by writing

```
new Rectangle(lenth);
new Rectangle(height);
```

...right? You'd call `new Rectangle(length, height)`. So, change

```
public Cuboid (double len, double wid, double hei){ 
  super(len);
  super(wid);
  height = hei;
}
```

to

```
public Cuboid (double len, double wid, double hei){ 
  super(len, wid);
  height = hei;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, now I understand why it said required: double, double. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`Cuboid`'s `Rectangle` superclass receives two arguments but when you call it in a subclass `Rectangle` with `super` you supply only one. Instead of this:

```
 super(len);
 super(wid);
```

Do this: `super(len,wid)` - `super(parameter list)` calls superclass constructor with a matching parameter list. And you can't call constructor two times. Even at the JVM bytecode level, a chain of  methods can be called at most once on any given object. And second error tells exactly about this: `error: call to super must be first statement in constructor
      super(wid);`

Comment: Thank you! I understand now why it said required: double, double. Thanks for responding so fast!